# prevent pass-by-ref of temporary object

Tags: c++, pass-by-reference, rvalue-reference, pass-by-rvalue-reference

I have a class that 'remembers' a reference to some object (e.g. an integer variable).  I can't have it reference a value that's destructed immediately, and I'm looking for a way to protect the users of my class from doing so by accident.

Is an rvalue-reference overload a good way to prevent a temporary to be passed in?

```
struct HasRef {
    int& a;
    HasRef(int& a):a(a){}
    void foo(){ a=1; }
};


int main(){
    int x=5;
    HasRef r1(x);
    r1.foo();  // works like intended.

    HasRef r2(x+4);
    r2.foo(); // dereferences the temporary created by x+4

 }
```

Would a private rvalue overload do?

```
 struct HasRef {
   int& a;
   HasRef( int& a ):a(a){}
   void foo(){ a=1; }
 private: 
   HasRef( int&& a );
 };

 ... HasRef r2(x+1); // doesn't compile => problem solved?
```

Are there any pitfalls I didn't see?

Comment: A temporary doesn't bind to an lvalue reference. The definition of `r2` in your first example should not compile.

Comment: If you are using VC++, one solution is to turn up the warning level and it will tell you when it doesn't work.

Comment: However, a _const_ reference would bind to a temporary, so the question is still a very good one.  I've considered this approach, but I'm still of the opinion that if a class is going to store a reference (or pointer) to the referenced object, it's better to take a pointer in the constructor, to make potential lifetime concerns a bit more obvious (when a constructor takes a pointer, usually it makes me think twice about what the object is going to do with it).

Comment: @musiphil,@Dave: indeed; I've mind-distilled this class from something from my day job which caused a crash in VS10, but ran smoothly in gcc4.4; will provide better code tomorrow.

Comment: @JamesMcNellis: But if it's a const reference, then it extends the lifetime of the temporary, so it's no longer a problem.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley:  No, it extends the lifetime of the temporary only until construction completes.  After the object is constructed, `a` refers to a no-longer-existent object.

Comment: Of course, I should have said "A temporary doesn't bind to a non-const lvalue reference." :-)

Comment: @xtofl, can you find other questions for which the [tag:pass-by-rvalue-reference] tag could apply?  It seems exceptionally specific to this question only, and that's not really a good case for a new tag.

Comment: @Charles: it is, indeed, a new tag.  It's a quite new concept, too.  Maybe there are tags for 'forwarding' etc..., but I didn't try look it up.  I'll dig into it.

Answer (score 7):

If you have to store a `const` reference to some instance of type `B` into your class `A`, then surely you want to be ensured, that lifetime of `A` instance will be exceeded by the lifetime of `B` instance:

```
B b{};
A a1{b}; // allowed
A a2{B{}}; // should be denied
B const f() { return B{}; } // const result type may make sense for user-defined types
A a3{f()}; // should also be denied!
```

To make it possible you should explicitly to `= delete;` all the constructor overloadings, which can accept rvalues (both `const &&` and `&&`). For this to achieve you should just to `= delete;` only `const &&` version of constructor.

```
struct B {};

struct A
{
    B const & b;
    A(B const & bb) : b(bb) { ; } // accepts only `B const &` and `B &`
    A(B const &&) = delete; // prohibits both `B &&` and `B const &&`
};
```

This approach allows you to prohibit passing to the constructor all kinds of rvalues.

This also works for built-in scalars. For example, `double const f() { return 0.01; }`, though it cause a warning like:

> warning: 'const' type qualifier on return type has no effect [-Wignored-qualifiers]

it still can has effect if you just `= delete;` only `&&` version of constructor:

```
struct A
{
    double const & eps;
    A(double const & e) : eps(e) {} // binds to `double const &`, `double &` AND ! `double const &&`
    A(double &&) = delete; // prohibit to binding only to `double &&`, but not to `double const &&`
};

double const get_eps() { return 0.01; }

A a{0.01}; // hard error
A a{get_eps()}; // no hard error, but it is wrong!
```

For non-conversion constructors (i.e. non-unary) there is an issue: you may have to provide `= delete;`-d versions for all the combinatorically possible versions of constructors as follows:

```
struct A
{
    A(B const &, C const &) {}
    A(B const &&, C const &&) = delete;
    // and also!
    A(B const &, C const &&) = delete;
    A(B const &&, C const &) = delete;
};
```

to prohibit mixed-cases like:

```
B b{};
A a{b, C{}};
```

Comment: Good point, the multi arg constructors!  Probably it would make sense to make all params templated, and statically assert all are lvalue references somehow.  That would prevent mix-explosion.

Comment: @xtofl Simple `static_assert` is not a good choise, when you apply a type trait like `std::is_constructible` to `A`. You need to SFINAE-out bad combinations or to use *Concept Lite* if avaliable.

Answer (score 3):

Ignoring the fact the code isn't valid and just answering the question about the private overload...

In C++11 I would prefer a deleted function to a private function. It's a bit more explicit that you *really* can't call it (not even if you're a member or friend of the class.)

N.B. if the deleted constructor is `HasRef(int&&)=delete` it will not be chosen here:

```
int i;
HasRef hr(std::forward<const int>(i));
```

With an argument of type `const int&&` the `HasRef(const int&)` constructor would be used, not the `HasRef(int&&)` one. In this case it would be OK, because `i` really is an lvalue, but in general that might not be the case, so this might be one of the very rare times when a *const* rvalue reference is useful:

```
HasRef(const int&&) = delete;
```

Answer (score 2):

That shouldn't compile. A good C++ compiler (or really almost any C++ compiler that I've ever seen) will stop that from happening.

Comment: thanks; it seems that I have to take a better look at my code and rephrase the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you're compiling in MSVS. In that case, turn off language extensions and you should get an error.

Otherwise, not that even marking the reference `const` extends the lifetime of the temporary until the constructor finishes. After that, you'll refer to an invalid object.

Comment: It is more easily said than done. Disabling languages extensions with MSVC makes their own standard library complain.

Comment: @AlexandreC. I've had no problems so far... lucky?

Comment: Probably. I recall having had problems with MSVC2005.

Comment: My understanding is that the Standard Library headers should work under /Za, but the Windows SDK headers (Windows.h and friends) may not.